# android video view issue - buffer

Tags: android, video

I have android app and video file which is bufferring and running from my application. I have tested that in samusung galaxy s2 and samsung galaxy tab. It works perfectly, but when i try that in karbon A21 and HTC Evo it says "Cannot play video sorry, this video cannot be played". Can somebody help me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's all related video codec format support compatibility. you didn't specify your video file extension. mp4 format supports most of all android devices.so, check any mp4 format in all android devices including your karbon A21 and htc devices. good luck!!!!!!!!

Comment: It is mp4 video file and codec:H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part-10)(avc1) and resolution :1230x720 , frame rate: 29.917000, Decoded format: planer 4:2:0 YUV and video file size is 55 MB

Comment: please try this code.           File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                       "test.mp4");
    if (clip.exists()) {
      video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
      video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
      ctlr=new MediaController(this);
      ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
      video.setMediaController(ctlr);
      video.requestFocus();
video.start(); otherwise please check other mp4 video is played or not. if it play then your video have some problem in video codec have to give permission for all video types like .mp4||.3gp||.wav like this